# How to optimize creation of huge amount of objects in Django Models

Tags: django, django-models

I am trying to read a CSV of 200k data and create Django models and save them using bulk_create, but the model creations code (i.e. `users_list.append(User(phone_number=phone_number)` ) is taking too much time to create all the models, is there any way to make it fast?

Comment: You could write sql statements directly. Maybe with raw(). See: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/sql/ or with custom sql: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/sql/#executing-custom-sql-directly

Comment: how much time does it take?

Comment: 20 min. but the main problem is that I can't use raw queries